# Cannot extract ZIP archive anymore

Tags: windows-10, zip

I have noticed a wierd issue with .zip archives:

I can easily compress files, but when I try to open any archive (even the ones I created), nothing happens.
I tried to click on the "Extract all..." menu entry, but every file appears to be damaged.

My OS is Windows 10 and 7-zip works flawlessly so at the moment I am sticking with it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like the archives are corrupt

Comment: They are not. I right-click on a file, **compress it and immediately after**, without moving it, I try to open it and it doesn't. If it is corrupted it is still a problem because my OS cannot create a decent ZIP...

Comment: Well 7-zip fully supports Windows 10

Comment: As I previously said: "7-zip works flawlessly so at the moment I am sticking with it."  But I would like to use the Windows Explorer in certain situations

Comment: I had to set Windows Explorer as the default program (again) and it started working again. Thank you for your valuable tips.